# Inorder successor of Threaded Binary Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am writing a c program to create threaded binary tree and then to find **INORDER SUCCESSOR** of a particular node. For this, i am displaying inorder sequence for the TBT constructed and then asking user to input the node to which successor is to be displayed.. I have written function to do this. But i am not getting successor for the FIRST NODE .. Last node's successor is 0 any ways its working fine.. Can any one help me fix this ? 
Here is the whole program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct tbtnode {
       int data;
       struct tbtnode *left,*right;
       int lbit,rbit,flag;
       int child;
}*root=NULL;

typedef struct tbtnode TBT;


TBT *insuc(TBT *t);




void inorder(TBT *);

void create(TBT *);

void create(TBT *root)
{
   int x,op,flag,y;
   flag=0;
   char ch;
   TBT *curr=root;
   TBT *q,*p;
 do
   {

     printf("\nCurrent node %d \n\n 1.Left Direction.\n\n2.Right Direction",curr->data);
     printf("\nEnter ur choice :");
     scanf("%d",&op);
     switch(op)
     {
        case 1: if(curr->lbit==1)
                {
                    printf("Enter left child of %d : ",curr->data);
                    scanf("%d",&x);
                    q=(TBT *)malloc(sizeof(TBT));
                    q->data=x;
                    q->lbit=q->rbit=1;
                    q->left=curr->left;
                    q->right=curr;
                    curr->left=q;
                    curr->lbit=0;
                    q->child=0;
                    flag=1;
                }
                else
                    curr=curr->left;
                break;
        case 2: if(curr->rbit==1)
                {

                    printf("Enter right child of %d :",curr->data);
                    scanf("%d",&x);
                    q=(TBT *)malloc(sizeof(TBT));
                    q->data=x;
                    q->lbit=q->rbit=1;
                    q->left=curr;
                    q->right=curr->right;
                    curr->right=q;
                    curr->rbit=0;
                    q->child=1;
                    flag=1;
                }
                else
                    curr=curr->right;
                break;
    }
  }while(flag==0);
}



void inorder(TBT *head)
   {
    TBT *t;
    t=head->left;
    printf("\n");
    while(t->lbit==0)
    t=t->left;
      while(t!=head)
       {
     printf("  %d",t->data);
     t=insuc(t);
       }
   }

TBT *insuc(TBT *t)
   {
     if(t->rbit==0)
      {
      t=t->right;
       while(t->lbit==0)
      t=t->left;
      return(t);
      }
     else
       return(t->right);
    }


void inorder_successor(TBT *head,int x)
   {
    TBT *t;
    t=head->left;
    printf("\n");
    while(t->lbit==0)
    t=t->left;
      while(t!=head)
       {   
           t=insuc(t);
           if(t->data==x)
           { 
                t=insuc(t);
                printf("  %d",t->data);
            }
       }
   }


int main()
  {

    int op,x,n,i=0,item;
    char ch;
    TBT *head,*root,*succ;       //here head indicates dummy variable

    head=(TBT *)malloc(sizeof(TBT));
    head->left=head;
    head->right=head;
    head->lbit=1;
    head->rbit=1;

      do
      {
     printf("\n****Threaded binary tree operations****");
     printf("\n1)create\n2)inorder\n3)Successor\n4)exit");
     printf("\nEnter ur choice: ");
     scanf("%d",&op);
  switch(op)
   {
    case 1:

    printf("\nEnter Number Of Nodes :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter root data: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

     root=(TBT *)malloc(sizeof(TBT));
     root->data=x;
     root->lbit=root->rbit=1;
     root->child=0;
     root->left=head->left;

     head->left=root;
     head->lbit=0;
     root->right=head->right;


     for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
      create(root);

      break;

    case 2:
    printf("\nInorder Traversal Is:\n");
      inorder(head);
      break;

    case 3: printf("Enter the node to which successor is to be found\n");
            scanf("%d",&item);
            inorder_successor(head,item);
            break;
    case 4:
      return(0);
      break;
    }
 }while(op<=4);
return 0;
}
```

please fix - inorder_successor() function for me.. 
Thank you

Comment: Step though the code in a debugger, line by line. If you don't find the problem, hopefully you can narrow it down and only show us the relevant code instead of everything.

Comment: unfortunately, i am using Mac, and i dont know how can i run debugger in gcc mac :(

Comment: `gdb` can't be installed like `gcc`, on the Mac ?..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, its going wrong in inorder_successor() .. its not giving the successor for the very first node of inorder sequence ..

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems with your code. To start with you never check for `NULL` pointers. To continue, you have both a global and a local variable in `main` called `root`.

The last thing means that when you allocate memory for `root` in `main`, you allocate for the local variable, and the global variable will still be `NULL`.

There are also other things that look weird, like you assigning the `left` and `right` pointer of `head` to itself.

I think you need to lay it all out on paper first, both how you have it now and how you want it to be. It will help you to better visualize the tree.